# How to manually refresh an object attached to the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using angular js and a directive for google chart (http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/). I have my google chart displaying within my graphController

```
<div ng-controller="graphController">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <input type="button" value="All time" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{ active: activeChart === 'alltime' }" ng-click="changeChart('alltime')" />
        <input type="button" value="Today" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{ active: activeChart === 'today' }" ng-click="changeChart('today')"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div google-chart chart="chart" />
    </div>            
</div>
```

And this chart is attached to my scope like so

```
$scope.chart = {
    // initialization  of initial values
}
```

Additionally, I am updating the values of this chart through a service, which I want to call when the buttons 'alltime' or 'today' are clicked.

```
$scope.changeChart = function changeChart(chart) {

    $scope.activeChart = chart;

    $scope.chart = {};
    $scope.chart = activityDataService.createGraph(activityDataService.getActivityData());      
};
```

The first time I click on either 'alltime' or 'today', the function runs and returns the result of my new chart. The second time I click on either button, I can verify that the service functions are called, but my chart object on the $scope is not updated. Is there a manual method to refresh a google chart? (Or some other refactoring on my end?)

Comment: What is activityDataService.createGraph? To refresh the char you just need to assign it to the new data. Shouldn't the chart parameter somehow be used to create a new graph?

Comment: have you tried scope.$apply()?